# Laplace transform of multiplication

Tags: fourier-transform, laplace-transform

I'm reading in my notes that $\mathcal{L}\left( h\left( t \right) x\left( t \right) \right) = \left( H * X \right)\left( s \right)$.

[$*$ is the convolution]

I'm surprised not to see the $\frac{1}{2 \cdot \pi}$ factor in the Laplace transform (as we have it in Fourier transform), is that a mistake in my notes?

Comment: No. The $2\pi$ only appears in the inverse transform as part of the contour integral definition.

Comment: But there is the $\frac{1}{2 \cdot \pi}$ factor for the Fourier equivalent right ? I'm surprised as I thought properties of those transforms were the same.

Comment: The same? "Yes."

Comment: I don't get it, there's a $\frac{1}{2 \cdot \pi}$ factor for Fourier and there isn't for Laplace, so ..  it's not the same ? I'm confused

Comment: Also, I'm seeing a $\frac{1}{2 \cdot \pi}$ factor for the Laplace transformation of a multiplication on Wikipedia (but they wrote it in the form of an integral), I'm not sure how to link all this

Answer (score 0):

The $2\pi$ in the Fourier transform appears because of its relationship to the Fourier series (and, consequently, periodic functions). While you can get Laplace from Fourier by making a suitable variable change, we should note that the $2\pi$ has a slightly different meaning here.

If $f$ admits a Laplace transform $F$, then the way to formally recover $f$ is by the integral

$$ f(t) = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{c - i\infty} ^{c + i\infty} e^{st} F(s) \ ds $$

where the integral ranges over a line in the complex plane containing the poles of the integrand to its right. The $2\pi$ here has nothing to do with its relationship in the Fourier transform, but is here because of the residue theorem.